# How do I insert multi image with restFul service?

Tags: hooks, media

I have a little issue I try to add to my node with RESTful service on Drupal 7 multiple `fid`s for a image gallery and I can't finish the process, I try

```
'field_gallery[und][0][]' => array(
  'fid:2381',
  'fid:2375',
),
```

and I don't know where I do it wrong. This is a request with php curl.

```
<div class="image-widget-data"><input type="file" class="form-file" size="22" name="files[field_gallery_und_0][]" id="edit-field-gallery-und-0-upload" multiple="multiple">
  <input type="submit" class="form-submit ajax-processed" value="Upload" name="field_gallery_und_0_upload_button" id="edit-field-gallery-und-0-upload-button">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="field_gallery[und][0][_weight]">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="field_gallery[und][0][fid]">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="field_gallery[und][0][display]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to end up with something more like:

```
'field_gallery[und][0]' => 2381,
'field_gallery[und][1]' => 2375,
```

The second level of array indexing is the field position. So the first file id goes into `[0]` and the second into `[1]`.